# Setting sessiontimeout in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay-6

I want to reduce the **session timeout** from **30 minutes to 5 minutes.**
I went through the guidelines of Liferay communtiy like setting following properties in to portal-ext.properties file.

```
session.timeout=5

session.timeout.warning=0

session.timeout.auto.extend=true
```

But this is not working.
Can any body help me please.

Comment: try with this "Liferay\bundles\liferay-portal-6.0.6\tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml "<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

Comment: One point I need to mention here. web.xml properties also override with portal-ext.properties file.

Comment: I tried with with .../ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml <session-timeout>5</session-timeout> but not working its taking 30 min only for sessiontimeout.

Comment: try with this session.timeout=5
session.timeout.warning=0
session.timeout.auto.extend=false..and restart server

Comment: @Lucky boy I tried with the properties which you have mentioned above and I commented out the code in web.xml <!-- <session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
 </session-config> --> but still the session is not expiring.

Comment: :- "We need to set session-timeout properties in portal-ext.properties and web.xml as well Because This value is always overridden by the value set in web.xml."

Comment: you mean to say i need to set the session-timeout value in both portal-ext.properties and web.xml is it correct.

Comment: refer this link" https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12518399"

Comment: @LuckyBoy Thanks Dude. I tried with changing session-timeout in portal-ext.properties and ../webaps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml Its is working now.

Comment: if you don't have any problem i am converting this comments into answer so that it will be helpful to other community members

Comment: Ya fine. It will be helpful to other also.

Comment: mark it as answer if this solves your problem

Answer (score 5):

**Session Time out** can be set in **portal-ext.properties** and **web.xml**

i.e

**portal-ext.properties**

```
session.timeout=5
session.timeout.warning=0
session.timeout.auto.extend=false
```

**web.xml**

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in this thread: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/35735320

> Change tomcat-{version}\conf\web.xml and
>   tomcat-{version}\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml by setting
>   session-timeout to 2 or even comment them out.

In your case change from

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

to

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Also, as I noticed, the value of 0 disables timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the default timeout for the portal (Liferay) and the application server (tomcat for example).

The portal timeout is in [tomcat]/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The tomcat timeout is in [tomcat]/conf/web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

After a restart, you can check the Liferay Control Panel, in Server / Server Administration: choose Properties > Portal Properties, and search for "**session.timeout**".

You should see your new timeout value.

Hope this helps,
Philippe